# Setting and retrieving a properties value in OOP PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

With the following function I am trying to pull data from a database, if necessary, and display the results on the view page, using OOP PHP. This function pulls the data from the DB:

```
function getdata () {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","XXXX");
    if (!$con)
        {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("user", $con);
        $sql="SELECT major FROM Education WHERE id=1";
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    mysql_close($con);

    }
```

So the previous function gets the college major of the active user from the database. It's only called if that value is set, like so:

```
function recommender () {
        if (isset($this->collegemajor)) {
            echo "Your major is on Facebook. You're majoring in $this->collegemajor.";
        } else {
            $this->getdata();
            echo "Your major is in the DB. You're majoring in $this->collegemajor_db";
        }
    }
```

And the value of collegemajor_db is set as follows:

```
     $collegemajor = isset($user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name']) ? $user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name'] : null ;
     $collegemajor_db = isset($row['major']) ? $row['major'] : null ;

     $profile = new profile ($collegemajor, $collegemajor_db);
     $profile->recommender();
```

For some reason, when I run this code, $this->collegemajor_db isn't populating. The DB connection works, I'm just having a problem setting the value of the object property collegemajor_db (I guess).

Comment: Are you missing the initial this in: `$this->collegemajor_db = isset($row['major']) ? $row['major'] : null ;` or was that just a transposition error?

Comment: Where you set the `$collegemajor_db` value? (You show sentence but I ask about where place this sentence is executed)

Comment: On comment 1, it's not in an object context. It's outside of the class, I edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm... I could be completely off here since I'm kinda new to oop, but shouldn't your function return a value? Maybe `return $row;` or `return $result;`. Like I said, I could be wrong, but I think that could be the issue.

Comment: What about that SQL query. Is there a row with id set as 1? Is that going to be hard-coded in there like that?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Probably not but I want to get the basics down first.